# date time picker to current date based on set programatically

Tags: c#

can i know what is wrong with the following statement as i am getting an error. I basically want to display in datetimepicker based on specified current month programatically

```
  dateTimePickerClassMonthRename.Value =DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM");
```

Comment: Please write the error that you got!

Answer (score 0):

The `Value` property of the `DateTimePicker` object is of type `DateTime`.This means that you cannot set it to a `string`,like you tried in the example above.

Just change you expression to this and it will work :

`dateTimePickerClassMonthRename.Value = DateTime.Now;`

So if your date is 1 Jan 2016 and the user clicks a button or triggers some other event the date will be set to the current month:

```
private void SetToCurrent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePickerClassMonthRename.Value = DateTime.Now;
}
```